# Uploading images on DropBox from my IOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on an IOS application in which i have to upload images on DropBox,but when i upload images on iPhone simulator at a time only 5-6 images uploaded and i am getting the problem like connection time out(-1005),network error always ->

```
2014-06-10 11:42:53.283 PicBackMan_1[2602:60b] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/metadata/dropbox/Photos - (404) Path '/Photos' not found  
2014-06-10 11:42:53.285 PicBackMan_1[2602:60b] restClient:loadMetadataFailedWithError: The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 404.)  
2014-06-10 11:42:55.167 PicBackMan_1[2602:60b] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files_put/dropbox/Super_12/PicBackMan-41.jpg - (-1005) Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)" UserInfo=0xa53b1d0 {destinationPath=/Super_12/PicBackMan-41.jpg, sourcePath=/Users/bettermac9/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/F51F7F8F-91C5-4E67-90E6-4218941D3A67/Documents/image.jpg}
```

i am getting these types of various error .IS there any problem with the iPhone Simulator.Is it work properly on the iPhone device?
please help me out.

My code for uploading images on DropBox

```
- (void)_startUpload:(UIImage *)image
{
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    NSLog(@"%@",(NSString*)countere);
}];
// while(countere != 0){
HUD=[[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:HUD];

HUD.labelText=@"Please wait for Uploading";
HUD.dimBackground=YES;
[HUD show:YES];

//NSString *fileString=@"/%@",albumNAME;
//  NSData * JPEGData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
self.file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",albumNAME];
NSLog(@"File Name ---> %@",self.file);
NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 100;
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PicBackMan-%ld.jpg",(long)randomNumber];
NSArray *pathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                        NSUserDomainMask,
                                                        YES);
countere--;
NSString *localPath = [[pathList objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];;
NSLog(@"local Path ----> %@",localPath);
NSString *destDir = self.file;
count4++;
// [presenter presentHud:@"Uploading"];
[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
if (count4%4==0) {
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    NSLog(@"Background Thread Running");
}
//[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
//   }
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(savingDone) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];   
}
```

Comment: Show the code you're using. Don't try to upload more than around 4 requests concurrently...

Comment: @wain:sir,this is my code for uploading images on DropBox->

Comment: Please take time to format your question so it's readable...

Comment: @wain sorry for my mistake sir, so if you get the problem please help me out .How could i upload more than 5 images at a single selection from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use an operation queue to limit the number of concurrent uploads. Or, use `NSURLSessionUploadTask`, and set the `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` on the `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.

Comment: thank you for your help,i will do with this methods.

Comment: is there any problem with the simulator,will uploading works fine with the iPhone device??

Comment: If it doesn't work on the sim then it generally won't work on a device.

Comment: Thank you sir, i am trying to modify the error of uploading.